# Advanced stylsheet in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-4

[image]

I want to implement a similar design for my blog so for the first post I have do this in my view `<%if @posts.first == post %> class="first-post" <%end%>`now I want to differentiate the third 5 7 ... posts from the 2 4 .. posts how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `pop` the first object out of the array:

```
post = @posts.pop
```

Then you can do what you like with it. Maybe render a partial. Then you can loop over the remaining posts. If you need granular control you can use array `slice`:

```
<% @posts.each_slice(2) do |slice| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% slice.each do |post| %>
      <div class="item">
        show item here
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This will split the array in groups of two, giving you more granular control over the layout.

Or, a suggested improvement to msanteler's answer:

```
<% @posts.each_with_index do |post, i| %>
  <% if i == 0 %>
    show stuff
  <% elsif i.even? %>
    show stuff
  <% else %>
    show stuff
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Good call on `.even?` just note that `index` starts with 0, not 1

Answer (score 0):

Edited for clarity and simplicity:

```
<% @posts.each_with_index do |p, index| %>

  <% position = index+1 %>

  <% if position == 1 then %>
    FIRST
  <% elsif (position.even?) then %>
    EVEN
  <% else %>
    ODD
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```